# How to create an animation dependent on other objects

Tags: animation, unreal-engine

I'm new to Blender and Unreal Engine, but I'm playing around with both. I want to have a character and a climbing animation. It should basically be an animation of the character climbing up a tree (for example: with a rope around the feet). What I'm wondering is, how do I create this animation, if it is dependent on in-game objects, like the tree. Trees vary in the angles they grow up, in the diameter, and more like that.

Any inputs here? Feels even hard for me to search for the right thing I want to accomplish ^^

Thanks in advance & Kind regards!

Comment: How far in the process are you? What have you tried so far, and where are you having trouble exactly? Questions here work best when they are *specific* and focused so they can have direct and focused answers, and so they are not too broad. Please read the [tour] for more information on that, and please [edit] your question to add new information re progress.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: i know how classic animations work. I'll want a hint for such special cases. How do i tackle such a problem lile described above, climbing a tree animation. Trees with different angle growing out of the ground, different diameter... Do i need to make for nearly each tree a seperate animation and check in code to load the correct animation or is there anyway to make some sort of parameterized animation? What is the way to go here?